# How to search for books that have spaces in their title using Google books API

Tags: python

When i search for books with a single name(e.g bluets) my code works fine, but when I search for books that have two names or spaces (e.g white whale) I got an error(jinja2 synatx) how do I solve this error?

```
   @app.route("/book", methods["GET", "POST"])
   def get_books():
    api_key = 
    os.environ.get("API_KEY") 
    if request.method == "POST":
     book = request.form.get("book")    
     url =f"https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q={book}:keyes&key={api_key}" 
     response =urllib.request.urlopen(url) 
     data = response.read() 
     jsondata = json.loads(data) 
    return render_template ("book.html", books=jsondata["items"]
```

I tried to search for similar cases, and just found one solution, but I didn't understand it
Here is my error message
http.client.InvalidURL

http.client.InvalidURL: URL can't contain control characters. '/books/v1/volumes?q=white whale:keyes&key=AIzaSyDtjvhKOniHFwkIcz7-720bgtnubagFxS8' (found at least ' ')

Comment: Please [edit] your question and format your code (use the `{}` button); this is especially important for Python where indentation matters. Include the error and stack trace as well as the input that causes the error. See [ask].

Comment: Roger Mr.robert

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: format code because you have all in one line and it is unreadable.

Comment: if you manually create URL then you have to also manually escape some chars - it may need to use `+` or `%20` instead of space. Other chars may also need to escape. You should check `urllib.parser` for functions to escape url.

Comment: when I run with `requests` then it work - maybe it escape all chars in ULR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some chars in url need to be encoded - in your situation you have to use `+` or `%20` instead of space.

This url has `%20` instead of space and it works for me. If I use `+` then it also works

```py
import urllib.request
import json

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=white%20whale:keyes&key=AIzaSyDtjvhKOniHFwkIcz7-720bgtnubagFxS8'
#url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=white+whale:keyes&key=AIzaSyDtjvhKOniHFwkIcz7-720bgtnubagFxS8'

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
text = response.read()
data = json.loads(text)

print(data)
```

With `requests` you don't even have to do it manually because it does it automatically

```py
import requests

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=white whale:keyes&key=AIzaSyDtjvhKOniHFwkIcz7-720bgtnubagFxS8'

r = requests.get(url)
data = r.json()

print(data)
```

You may use [urllib.parse.urlencode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) to make sure all chars are correctly encoded.

```py
import urllib.request
import json

payload = {
    'q': 'white whale:keyes',
    'key': 'AIzaSyDtjvhKOniHFwkIcz7-720bgtnubagFxS8',
}

query = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload)

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?' + query

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
text = response.read()
data = json.loads(text)

print(data)
```

and the same with `requests` - it also doesn't need encoding

```py
import requests

payload = {
    'q': 'white whale:keyes',
    'key': 'AIzaSyDtjvhKOniHFwkIcz7-720bgtnubagFxS8',
}

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes'

r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
data = r.json()

print(data)
```